# When domain administrators install apps from the gsuite marketplace: which service account get the permissions?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, service-accounts, google-workspace

I'm following the instruction here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority about domain wide delegation.

> Note: When you use G Suite Marketplace to install an application for your domain, the required permissions are automatically granted to the application. You do not need to manually authorize the service accounts that the application uses

Now my question is, how the required permissions are granted to the application? How am I using those permissions? Is it limited only to Google Scripts, or I can use the permissions from my NodeJS app?

If I can use from NodeJS (Rest), which service account should I use for that?